# Send http request multiple times in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, httprequest

I'm trying to send the same http request multiple times. I just put the request in a loop, but when I run the code it shows the response 1 time.

```
const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode} ${res.statusMessage}`)

  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

for(i=0; i<3; i++){ 
      req.write(data)
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you trying to use this with?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am trying to send a post request to an external api. It works well, but I get just one response.  I am using basic node.js

Comment: I think you need to keep the connection open

Comment: But `req.write` does not make a HTTP request...?

Comment: @jeremyThile I know. I have configured the request before

Comment: Ha, now there's a HTTP call. But there's just one. You said, `I just put the request in a loop`, but clearly it's not. There's one HTTP call, and _then_ there's a loop. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the request inside the for loop:

```
for(i=0; i < 3; i++){ 
const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode} ${res.statusMessage}`)

  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
});
req.write(data);
}
```